# Openshift rhc port-forward timeout

Tags: openshift

I've noticed that every 2-3 minutes, my rhc port-forward goes timeout and disconnects. Is there a way to prevent this? The only work around I did is that I created a script that connects to my mysql database 127.0.0.1 every 20 secs just to prevent the idling!